# C#.Net - How to cancel a BackgroundWorker pulling data from a WebService

Tags: c#, web-services, multithreading, backgroundworker

I've got the following code:

```
void ReferenceManager_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {

        // Get the raw data
        byte[] data = this.GetData(IvdSession.Instance.Company.Description, IvdSession.Instance.Company.Password);

        // Deserialize the list
        List<T> deseriaizedList = null;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data))
        {
            deseriaizedList = Serializer.Deserialize<List<T>>(ms);
        }

        // Convert the list to the Reference Interface
        List<IReference> referenceList = new List<IReference>();
        foreach (T entity in deseriaizedList)
        {
            IReference reference = (IReference)entity;
            referenceList.Add(reference);
        }

        e.Result = referenceList;

    }
    catch (WebException)
    {
        e.Result = null;
    }
}
```

The code is basically calling a delegate to a WebService method. Unfortunately, the main reason I used a background worker was to stop the UI freezing when loading the data. I've got a form that pops up saying please wait, click here to cancel.

On the click of cancel I call CancelAsync on the background worker. Now, as I'm not looping I cannot see a *nice* way of checking for a cancellation. The only option I can see is to have...

```
byte[] m_CurrentData;
```

...outside of the method and launch a new thread on the start of DoWork(..) that calls the webservice to populate m_CurrentData. I'd then need to perform a loop checking if cancelled or checking if m_CurrentData is no longer null.

Is there any better way of achieving a cancellation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual work seems to be done inside the `this.GetData(...)` method which is not shown. I gather it is calling a webservice. You probably should call the `Abort()` method on the proxy object to stop the client from waiting for the response. There is no point in calling `CancelAsync()`, just be sure to correctly check for errors in `RunWorkerCompleted()`. The easiest way is probably  **not** to catch any exceptions in `_DoWork()`, but check the Result.Error property in `Completed()`. You should do that anyway.

Just to clarify, the CancelAsync() method is only useful to stop a loop inside DoWork(). You are not running a (meaningful) loop there, so another approach is needed.

Comment: So easy! Just call WebService.Abort() and catch the exception! Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

I've just checked the [MSDN for `DoWorkEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.doworkeventargs.argument.aspx) and realised that my previous answer was wrong. There's the `CancellationPending` property on the `BackgroundWorker` which is set by by the call to `CancelAsync` ([from the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.cancellationpending.aspx)).  Thus your `DoWork` method can become:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // Do not access the form's BackgroundWorker reference directly.
    // Instead, use the reference provided by the sender parameter.
    BackgroundWorker bw = sender as BackgroundWorker;

    // Extract the argument.
    int arg = (int)e.Argument;

    // Start the time-consuming operation.
    e.Result = TimeConsumingOperation(bw, arg);

    // If the operation was canceled by the user, 
    // set the DoWorkEventArgs.Cancel property to true.
    if (bw.CancellationPending)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Can you use this?

Comment: Hi, DoWork has e.Cancel which provides the cancellation notification. My method does not loop though, so there's no way to check if e.Cancel has changed to true.

Comment: Ah - I read, but clearly didn't fully take in, that part of your question. I'll see if I can update the answer.